# Complex ERB replacement with HAML fails in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, haml, erb

I have replaced my ERB files with HAML which works great. However, I have some complex mixed javascript and erb code, which fails when converted to haml. I know about the ":plain" option to bypass haml, but when I do this with the code below, the erb code is just printed as text, but not interpreted. Do you guys have any solution?

ERB replacement with HAML fails in JS

```
  - if (@active == "tasks")
    :plain
      $('#content_output').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3><%= I18n.t :task_all %></h3><%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/all_tasks', :tasks => @contact_tasks, :layout => 'normal')) %></div>");
      $('#content_input').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3><%= I18n.t :task_new_title %></h3><%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/new_task')) %></div>");
      $('a#tasks_tab').addClass('active');
```

This is the original js.erb code:

```
    <% if (@active == "tasks") %>
        $('#content_output').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3><%= I18n.t :task_all %></h3><%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/all_tasks', :tasks => @contact_tasks, :layout => 'normal')) %></div>");
        $('#content_input').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3><%= I18n.t :task_new_title %></h3><%= escape_javascript(render('tasks/new_task')) %></div>");
        $('a#tasks_tab').addClass('active');
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file is of extension **js.haml**, I think that all you need to do is change your `<%= ... %>` tags to standard string interpolation tags `#{ ... }`:

```
- if (@active == "tasks")
  :plain
    $('#content_output').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3>#{I18n.t :task_all}</h3>#{escape_javascript(render('tasks/all_tasks', :tasks => @contact_tasks, :layout => 'normal'))}</div>");
    $('#content_input').html("<div class='content_title task'></div><h3>#{I18n.t :task_new_title}</h3>#{escape_javascript(render('tasks/new_task'))}</div>");
    $('a#tasks_tab').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:javascript` instead of `:plain`

BTW in Rails 3, you should use unobtrusive javascript (UJS). Check out some tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: When using :javascript, nothing is executed, clicking on tabs don't refresh the content, but with :plain it does, except it shows everything between "<%=  %>" as plain text.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you have Ruby code embedded in Javascript. I guess there's no easy way then - you should convert it to UJS. It's the best practice anyway.